# go get failing in Mac OS X while trying to do go install

Tags: macos, go

On Mac OS X while trying to do do `go get` by executing the command below. It is failing with the below error:-

```
jabongs-MacBook-Pro-4:florest debraj$ go get ./...
go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/common/config: open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build823644730/github.com/jabong/florest/src/common/config.a: no such file or directory
go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/common/utils/responseheaders: open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build823644730/github.com/jabong/florest/src/common/utils/responseheaders.a: no such file or directory
go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/service: open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build823644730/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service.a: no such file or directory
```

Below is the output using `-x` flag:-

```
jabongs-MacBook-Pro-4:florest debraj$ go get -x ./...
WORK=/var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build665863426
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples -complete -buildid febe48d3c570d8539844891977fbdc206dc458b4 -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./api_definition.go ./data_structures.go ./hello_world.go ./hello_world_health_checker.go ./hello_world_multipe_errors.go ./swagger.go
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service -complete -buildid f55b565340e2d0d690f5de8bd424fffb8895a331 -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./api_interface.go ./business_logic_executor.go ./config_manager.go ./constants.go ./dynamic_config_manager.go ./health_checker.go ./http_response_creator.go ./init_manager.go ./monitor_helper.go ./service_register.go ./service_version_helper.go ./service_workflow_data.go ./uri_interpreter.go ./web_server.go
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples -complete -buildid febe48d3c570d8539844891977fbdc206dc458b4 -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./api_definition.go ./data_structures.go ./hello_world.go ./hello_world_health_checker.go ./hello_world_multipe_errors.go ./swagger.go
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy -complete -buildid c16efba4536c81f8b5b9f0090f909c0b3c71383c -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./api_definition.go ./cache_strategy_user.go ./sample_db_adapter.go
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service/_obj/
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/jabong/florest/src/service -complete -buildid f55b565340e2d0d690f5de8bd424fffb8895a331 -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./api_interface.go ./business_logic_executor.go ./config_manager.go ./constants.go ./dynamic_config_manager.go ./health_checker.go ./http_response_creator.go ./init_manager.go ./monitor_helper.go ./service_register.go ./service_version_helper.go ./service_workflow_data.go ./uri_interpreter.go ./web_server.go
mkdir -p /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/
mv $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples.a /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples.a
mkdir -p /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/
cp $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a
go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples: open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build665863426/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a: no such file or directory
mkdir -p /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/
mv $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy.a /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples/cachestrategy.a
mv $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service.a /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/service.a
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/_obj/exe/
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest.a -trimpath $WORK -p main -complete -buildid fb73c44c8d0536fc3134f24ae052fdb67036f537 -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./main.go
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/
cd /Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest -complete -buildid 9936e7e44a8331913a166a228aa8e088d0b05adf -D _/Users/debraj/golang/src/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest -I $WORK -I /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -pack ./config_initialize.go ./logger_initialize.go ./service_initialize.go ./service_test_helper.go ./test_web_server.go
cp $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service.a /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service.a
go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/service: open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build665863426/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service.a: no such file or directory
cd .
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link -o $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/_obj/exe/a.out -L $WORK -L /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64 -extld=clang -buildmode=exe -buildid=fb73c44c8d0536fc3134f24ae052fdb67036f537 $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest.a
mkdir -p /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/
mv $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest.a /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/test/servicetest.a
mkdir -p /Users/debraj/golang/bin/
mv $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/_obj/exe/a.out /Users/debraj/golang/bin/florest
```

Can someone let me know why this error is coming? This is working perfectly fine on Ubuntu.

Version

- MacOS X - 10.11.4
- GoLang - 1.6.1

Comment: Pretty hard to know what's wrong since the repository is not publicly readable, so any attempt to debug would be a guess at best.

Comment: What it is trying to do `open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build823644730/github.com/jabong/florest/src/common/config.a`? I have not specified this folder structure neither in `GOROOT` or `GOPATH`

Comment: It's a temporary file.

Comment: Use the `-x` flag and see if any of the intermediate commands have any useful output.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of `-x` flag.

Comment: It looks like it's working and created `/Users/debraj/golang/bin/florest`.

Comment: All `go install` is failing `go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/service: open /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build665863426/github.com/jabong/florest/src/service.a: no such file or directory`

Comment: The compiled artifacts are missing for some reason. Are you out of disk space? Do you have some security software interfering with compilation? You can try using the `-work` option to leave the temp directory and inspect the permissions (though I assume that would error on file creation, rather than just leave them missing)

Comment: I don;t see any folder with name `go-build*` inside `/var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was found after discussing in [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-nuts/go$20get$20failing$20on$20mac/golang-nuts/EH1975DJMz8/VD45mbVWAQAJ). Just quoting it below again:-

> My guess is that's because Mac filesystem is case preserving but not
>   case-sensitive, meaning that in mac os "floRest" and "florest" is the
>   same file/directory while on linux those are 2 distinct files. (you
>   can configure mac filesystem to be case-sensitive as well, but that's
>   not the default).
>
> As you can see in the logs:
>
> mv $WORK/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples.a
>   /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/floRest/src/examples.a
>
> mkdir -p
>   /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/
>
> cp $WORK/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a
>   /Users/debraj/golang/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a
>
> go install github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples: open
>   /var/folders/lp/3q9_2mn51hd9s4yj_jcf3jxm0000gp/T/go-build665863426/github.com/jabong/florest/src/examples.a:
>   no such file or directory
>
> a file "floRest/src/examples.a" is moved and then there's an attempt
>   to copy "florest/src/examples.a", which is the same file on mac os,
>   and it's no longer there.

For cloning the repo I used:-

```
git clone https://github.com/jabong/florest/
```

So in mac my code checked out in a directory `florest`. But the actual repo name was `https://github.com/jabong/floRest/` and in code it was referenced as `floRest` which was causing the issue.